# should I release NSTimer if it has a repeats attribute equal to YES?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, release

Sometimes I get confused about when not releasing an object. I have:

```
NSTimer *timer2;

timer2 = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: (5)
                                         target: self
                                       selector: @selector(someMethod:)
                                       userInfo: nil
                                        repeats: YES];
```

and the method that get's executed every five seconds is:

```
-(void) someMethod:(NSTimer*)theTimer
{
   NSLog(@"code got executed");
}
```

I have another method that places another nib file on my root view controller:

```
ViewControllerObjetivos *control = [ViewControllerObjetivos alloc];

[control initWithNibName:@"ViewControllerObjetivos" bundle:nil];

UINavigationController *navControl = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                                      initWithRootViewController:control];

[self presentModalViewController:navControl animated:NO]; 
[navControl setNavigationBarHidden:YES];

[control release];
[navControl release];
```

when I call that last method a new nib file get's placed on the root view controller. And someMethod still gets called!

so I am confused if I should release the timer2 because I did not use the word init or alloc nor copy to initialize it. So what am I suppose to do? should I just stop it then call the last method that I showed? or maybe should I release the whole nib file since I am going to be working with a new one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct way to stop a timer is calling its [`invalidate`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html) method.

> invalidate
>
> Stops the receiver from ever firing again and requests its removal from its run loop.

In your case, you could store `timer2` in an ivar of your class and then send it `invalidate` at the proper moment, i.e., when you display the second nib (if I am not wrong). Not doing so will leave the timer running forever, as you witnessed.

If you set [`repeats`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSTimer/scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:invocation:repeats:) to `NO`, the timer will be automatically invalidating after firing the first time:

> repeats
>
> If YES, the timer will repeatedly reschedule itself until invalidated. If NO, the timer will be invalidated after it fires.

Comment: Sergio if I set the autorepeat property equal to NO do I still have to call the invalidate method?

Answer (score 1):

NSTimer's scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval returns an object that it owns, so you do not need to retain it.  If you need to invalidate it(stop it) later, you should retain it yourself.

Comment: It does not return an autoreleased object; it returns an object that you don't own.